# express server for serving Vue.js html file

Tags: express, heroku, vue.js

I wrote a Vue application using the CLI. I’ve run the build command and got the dist folder with html file and the associated js/css file etc. Now I want to host the app on heroku with node/express sever, what I’ve written only half works.

For the record I’m using the vue router to render different components at different routes.

```
const routes = [
  {path: "/", redirect: "/home"},
  {path: "/home", component: body},
  {path: "/home/new", component: create},
  {path: "/home/entry/:id", component: blog},
  {path: "/register", component: register},
  {path: "/logout", component: logout},
  {path: "/home/user/:userprofile", component: userprofile}

]
```

My vue application calls a separate backend API for all its data so the express server I’m requesting is only to server the html file across all routes.

This is what I have found from google:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app = express();

app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));

app.listen(port);
```

It works when I’m going to “/” route but when I go to “/home” or similar it returns an error “cannot GET /home” or similar.

Can someone write me a short and simple express sever app for deploying vue on Heroku please?

Comment: Are you using history mode or hash mode?

Comment: @LassiUosukainen I'm using history mode with <router-view> to render components according to route changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are missing configuration on your web server to redirect all requests to "/". VueJs router takes responsibility after that but it doesn't receive requests unless you explicitly configure your web server to do so.

[Here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) is a Vue Router documentation page with short code snippets for different web servers that you will need to add to your web server configuration.

Comment: I've got it You were right, I was deploying a different server file without a matching route pattern to serve the file. I can't believe I spent an hour scratching my head overlooking that.

Thank you for your help.